# Delay form submission before ajax call completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

as title states I'm struggling with making delayed post submission so ajax call can complete.

So far I've this, any ideas why it wouldn't work?

```
//Jquery
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#save").on("click", function(e){


                //Prevent submission of post data before ajax success in function reverse_geocoding
                e.preventDefault();
                //ajax
                reverse_geocoding(lat_onclick,lng_onclick,true);

        }
    });





                    function reverse_geocoding(latitude,longitude,submit) {
                            //get country/city/state using lat and long data
                            jQuery.ajax({
                                url: "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/reverse-geocoding.php",
                                type: "GET",
                                data: "latitude=" + latitude + "&longitude=" + longitude,
                                cache: false,
                                success: function (data){
                                    var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                                },
                                complete: function() {
                                    if (submit) {
                                        $("#add_to_map").submit();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    }
});
//End Jquery
```

html part:

```
<form method="post" name="update_profile_maps" id="add_to_map" action="">
    //some inputs here.
</form>
```

Comment: What happens that's wrong?

Comment: 1) Is your JavaScript code actually inside a PHP file? 2) What's supposed to happen to `response` in your `success` function, because you're not doing anything with it right now.

Comment: I haven't tested, but having this issue in the past, I've had to also return false as well as preventing the default.

Comment: @ExplosionPills form doesn't submit.

Comment: @user113215 yes. I edit out irrelevant parts.

Comment: Perhaps `$` isn't pointing to `jQuery`? Does your click handler for `#save` fire? Does the AJAX call happen, but `complete` doesn't fire?

Comment: @user113215 yes all that. David Smith solved it meanwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a `<submit>` tag, use a normal `<button>` (which is not of type `submit`; note that type `submit` [is the default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)). When the button is clicked, fire your ajax and then submit the form using JavaScript if the ajax completes successfully.